Apache 2.4 can't serve static content from Apache Web Server
I configured an Apache web server and Tomcat. I have a static folder that is contained within the Tomcat webapps folder. The css file that in static folder changes my webpage login screen color.
When I try to reach with localhost my login screen color changes as expected. But when I try to connect with domain that I declared in Apache Web Server it won't change, and returns following error;

https://test.webpage.com/static/login.css net::ERR_ABORTED 400

Here is my httpd.vhost.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName test.webpage.com
    ServerAlias www.test.webpage.com
    ErrorLog "logs/test-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/test-access.log" common

    <Directory "C:/Test/test2/AppServer/webapps/static/">
        Options +Indexes  
    AllowOverride None  
        Require all granted
    </Directory>  

    JkMount  /static/* prod
    JkMount  /static prod

</VirtualHost>

Example with localhost connection
Example with domain connection
What am I missing here?
Thank you.

There is no SSL and/or TLS configuration at the VirtualHost level so your website may not even support https and when it does ; a certificate is valid only for a specific domain and never for the localhost domain

Have a look at the developer tools in your browser when accessing the page. There are several scenarios where an explanation will manifest there. If it doesn't, check your webserver logs.
